# Retirar as setas no campo tipo number

Tags: html5

Colegas.

Estou usando o código abaixo para quando o usuário acessar pelo smartphone, aparecer o teclado de números:

```
<input type="number" value="" class="form-control">
```

Porém no desktop, quando clicamos dentro do campo, aparece setas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faria para otimizar e retirar essas setas? Teria alguma outra solução?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

baseado nessa :[pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024771/styling-a-input-type-number), você pode utilizar a propriedade [-moz-appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance), a qual é utilizada para exibir um elemento usando o estilo nativo da plataforma com base no tema do sistema operacional.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
}
input[type=number] { 
   -moz-appearance: textfield;
   appearance: textfield;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: Funciona em todos os navegadores?

Comment: Não, difícil algo que funciona em "todos" os navegadores....

Comment: Me referi aos mais conhecidos como chrome, firefox ou opera.

Comment: Hum, sim com a edição sim....

Comment: Testei esse código aqui e não funcionou, utiilizo o bootstrap.

Comment: O que não funcionou ? @ViniciusAquino

Comment: Opaa, eu coloquei esse código na minha folha de estilo e o input type number no meu formulário e as setinhas continuam aparecendo

Comment: tente colocar inline dentro do input... utilizando `style=""`

Comment: Agora foi, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

adicione este comando no seu css

```
<style>
 input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```